# Looks in "change the look" is missing after depolying a new look

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, composed-looks

I have created a custom composed look in VS.
The look works fine but the problem is that when i deploy the solution to Sharepoint online all other looks is getting dissappeared, this problem is not happining in sharepoint on-premm

This is the xml for my custom look.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

the solution is that the attribute `templateListType` should be `100` not `124`

100 is a General List, and 124 doesn't exist.